# Bootloader Arduino Uno Rev3

Tags: arduino

I want to load the arduino uno Rev3 boot loader to my 328P chip. I am using USB ASP and Extreme Burner.

I looked at arduino installation folder and there are several Hex files available under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\bootloaders\atmega". I guess I need to make use of ATmegaBOOT_168_atmega328.hex file as the name suggests. Also I understand that the fuse bit I need to select is efuse-0x05 hfuse-0xD6 and lfuse - 0xFF

Can anyone confirm this? Are there any other latest Hex files available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the file: `optiboot_atmega328.hex`

It is in the `optiboot` folder under bootloaders.

The normal fuses are:

```
low: FF
high: DE
extended: 05
```

Optiboot is the 512 byte bootloader, normally installed on the Uno chips.

---

[image: Bootloader size]

As you can see from the datasheet, a high fuse of DE gives a bootloader size of 256 *words* (that is, 512 bytes).

And the relevant entry in the `boards.txt` file for the Uno (the standard fuses when you burn the bootloader):

```
uno.name=Arduino Uno
uno.upload.protocol=arduino
uno.upload.maximum_size=32256
uno.upload.speed=115200
uno.bootloader.low_fuses=0xff
uno.bootloader.high_fuses=0xde
uno.bootloader.extended_fuses=0x05
uno.bootloader.path=optiboot
uno.bootloader.file=optiboot_atmega328.hex
uno.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
uno.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0F
uno.build.mcu=atmega328p
uno.build.f_cpu=16000000L
uno.build.core=arduino
uno.build.variant=standard
```

This confirms my suggested fuse settings.

Comment: According to datasheet, BOOTSZ1, BOOTSZ1 sets boot size as 128 if both are high. That means it is not 512 bytes!!  Therefore is it not high byte should be 0xDA? In fact in makefile I saw the entry as atmega328_isp: HFUSE = DA

Comment: See amended answer. It is in fact **256 words** (not 128) and 256 words is equal to 512 bytes. A high fuse of 0xDA would give you a 1024 word (2048 byte) bootloader, which is not Optiboot.

Comment: Thank You. I looked at 168 and hence fuse bits were wrong. But now I have another problem. My 328P chip is detected with 8 MHz crystal, but not with 16 MHz crystal. It looks like there is no change in fuse settings for both. I need to debug and see where the problem is. I am using extreme Burner

Comment: What crystal is on the board? Have you changed the fuses yet? With the fuses I recommended, and a 16 MHz crystal, it should run at 16 MHz.

Comment: Posted separately in the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716875/unable-to-connect-to-atmega328p-chip-with-16mhz-crystal