# Unable to connect to Atmega328P chip with 16MHz crystal

Tags: avr, atmega

I am trying to connect to Atmega328P chip through eXtreme Burner. I used 22pf capacitors and 10K pull for reset. 
I am able to read the chip if I use 8 MHz Crystal. But cannot read if I connect 16MHz crystal. When I looked at the datasheet, it says fuse bits are same for 8 MHz and 16 MHz. I get "Power On Failed"  error message with 16 MHz. I am using USBASP programmer.
Please note: With 8 MHz crystal, though I am able to read the device, I get error message "Incorrect Chip Found! Continue". If I press OK, it reads the data. The fuse bits read using 8 MHz crystal are: Low-- FF, High - DE, Extended -- FD, Lock Fuse - CF and Calibration - FFFFFFB1
What could be the issue?
Attached screen shots in the link 
http://www.filedropper.com/extremeburnererrors

Comment: maybe this should be moved to electrical engineering SE?

Answer (score 1):

Its not in your settings then, so it must be in the setup of your hardware. Try different capacitor values. If I remember correctly, you have to vary the value of the capacitors as the frequency of your crystal varies. Also you have to take in to account the added inductance and capacitance of the breadboard or pcb and solder. So I would suggest just trial and error with different capacitor values.

Comment: Tried with 33PF and 47PF. Let me get new crystal itself and see if there is a problem (Do not have oscilloscope to test the crystal itself)

Comment: The datasheet says 12pF - 22pF. If 22pF wasn't working use smaller. Are you using a breadboard? Also that error message "Incorrect chip found" always happens, I don't remember why anymore but it is fine, that means everything is working fine. That is a completely unrelated issue and actually isn't an issue at all.

Comment: I am using breadboard. Any extra care we need to take? Let me try with 12 pf and see. Also please note that I am unable to write Extended fuse bits as 05 using 8 Mhz Crystal. I get error message "Verification Failed" as indicated in the file given in link. I am able to change Low fuse bits (I just changed to Full Swing oscillator (F7) ) and it works fine.  Any thing I need to do for writing extended lock bits?

Comment: I also used the USBasp programmer & eXtreme Burner, but I used a ATmega16A & ATtiny13A and I never had any problem writing any of the fuse bits, so I don't know.

Comment: I managed to program using arduino Uno board. I feel that the issue is mostly in crystal itself. I am yet to get the 12pf cap and new crystal. I need to find some time and grab these teo components and test it. Will update sometime next week.